# SQL Server Select only searched numbers

Tags: sql-server

I have a column which contains category values like

```
11,2,3
114,3,2
etc.
```

Want to select top category from these unique numbers. I've tried to select 11th category with

```
select * 
from product 
where category like '%11%'
```

but this one select bot 11 and like 114. How can I only select the 11?

Comment: Then use = not like.

Comment: select * from product where category = 11

Comment: select * from product where category =  11

Comment: @Aldrin select * from product where category = '11' is empty because there is no column have only 11 value. they all have like 11,166,123 values. i want to select 11 here but only the 11 not 116 or something beside 11 before the comma

Comment: **DO NOT** store multiple values in a single columns! That's a horribly bad design and **will cause grief** sooner or later - just **don't do it!**

Comment: @marc_s i have categories,subcategories and subsubcategories. in products table i have a column like a category and inside that category_number,subcategory_number,subsubcategory_number. i store lik that and after that i delete commas and search all categories from top to sub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @Search varchar(25) = '11'
Select * from product where category+',' like '%'+@Search+',%'
```

Comment: this is my answer i guess.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX) = '11,2,3 114,3,2'

SELECT 1
WHERE ',' + @x + ',' LIKE '%,11,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a set based way and this is faster than like for bigger sets..[Using one of the functions from here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)..

```
declare @x='11,2,3 114,3,2'

;With cte
as
(select * from dbo.substring_numbers(@x,',')
)
select * from cte where item=11
```